# Moscow Seven Sisters

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math, combinatorial-geometry, tessellations

Fix $n$ points in the plane in generic position, i.e. no three of them on the same line, etc.
The number of lines joining two of them is ${n \choose 2}$.
The number of regions in which $\ell$ lines cut the plane is $\leq \ell (\ell+1)/2+1$.
By moving around in the plane, we observe the $n$ points in different circular orderings.
Since there are $(n-1)!$ such orderings, it is clear that for $n \geq 7$ we cannot observe the points in all distinct orderings, while for $n \leq 4$ this is possible.
What happens for $n=5$ and 6?

Comment: This is a very important missing piece of information, without which the question is unanswerable.  Who are Moscow seven sisters and how are they related to this problem?

Comment: @Batominovski For $n=7$, you get seven points, which you can picture as seven buildings in the city of Moscow, Wikipedia is your friend.

Comment: @jj_p: Requiring a reader to have to perform a web search to understand the context of a question is poor authorship. In this case, it would be most helpful for you to include your above comment as part of the question itself (not everyone reads comments), providing a specific link to whatever Wikipedia entry you believe is relevant.

Comment: @Blue That is just a curiosity, totally irrelevant to understand the math question..

Answer (score 2):

Here is just a small correction, the maximum number $F_n$ of possible regions created by straight lines passing through a given set of $n$ points is
$$F_n:=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }n\in\{0,1\}\,,\\3\binom{n}{4}+3\binom{n}{2}-n+1&\text{if }n=2,3,4,\ldots\end{cases}\,.$$
It is easy to show that
$$F_n<(n-1)!\text{ for }n=6,7,8,\ldots\,.$$

Thus, it remains to verify whether all cyclic permutations of the $n$ points can be seen on the plane when $n=5$.  After some trials, I believe that the answer for $n=5$ is that there does not exist such a point configuration. However, I have no proof.

Comment: Your $F_n$ is wrong, already for $n=4$. The correct one is the one I wrote. So $n=5$ and 6 cannot be discarded that way.

Comment: Show me a configuration with $4$ points such the lines connecting two of them create more than $18$ regions.  You probbly used the formula for $\displaystyle\binom{n}{2}$ lines in general position (where you can indeed create $\displaystyle\frac12\,\binom{n}{2}\,\Biggr(\binom{n}{2}+1\Biggl)+1$ regions), but these lines are not in general position.  The $n$ points are, and each of these points will be the intersection of $n-1$ lines.

Comment: I see, you are right. Your estimate is sharper.